# Trying to use react material-ui checkbox inside Dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use material-ui checkbox inside dialog but onChange function seems not working. Please refer the following info for my code:

```
<Dialog open={showAssetListDialog}>
        <DialogTitle id="responsive-dialog-title">
          <h3 className="formHeader">Asset List</h3>
          <hr />
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
        <Typography>  
        { availableAssets && Object.keys(assetList).map((key, index) => (
          <p>
           <Checkbox
             const asset_id = {assetList[index].value}
             checked = {assetList[index].asset_id}
             color   = "primary"
             onChange = {props.handleCheckboxChange('asset_id')}
             onCheck = {props.handleCheckboxChange}
           >
           </Checkbox>   
           {assetList[index].label}
          </p>

         ))}
        </Typography>  
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button
            color="success"
            className="btnSave"
            onClick={props.handleAssetListClose}
          >
           Done
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
```

Comment: You aren't passing `event.target.checked` to your `handleCheckboxChange`, so how are you setting the new value?

Comment: I just tried to console.log inside handleCheckboxChange. It simply didn’t display anything inside browser console.

Comment: Please show the code of what you tried. What does your handleCheckboxChange look like?

Comment: @RyanCogswell I just tried to console.log this way : handleCheckboxChange = name => event => {
    console.log("name is", name);
   // this.setState({ [name]: event.target.checked });
  };

Comment: Please reproduce your problem in a CodeSandbox and include it in your question.